# C++ Pointer Dereferenced Assignment

Tags: c++, c, pointers, visual-c++, dereference

I am trying to learn C++ by firstly going through the low level details before I start using abstractions such as std::copy or memcpy. Currently I am stuck in trying to figure out why this code is never assigning into "sortedArray" variable, when looking with debugger I dereference the value from "data" correctly but it is never assigned to "sortedArray". I see value such as "-842150451" instead of "14" for first value. Can you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong ? And any other issues there may be that I do not see or advice would be greatly appreciated !

```
void swap(int* bigger, int* smaller){
    *bigger += *smaller;
    *smaller = *bigger - *smaller;
    *bigger = *bigger - *smaller;
}

int* bubbleSort(int *data, int size){
    bool swapped = true;
    int *sortedArray = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < size;i++){
        *(sortedArray++) = *(data++);
    }

    while (swapped){
        swapped = false;
        for (int i = 1; i <= size - 1; i++){
            if (sortedArray[i - 1] > sortedArray[i]){
                swap(&sortedArray[i - 1], &sortedArray[i]);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        size--;
    }
    return sortedArray;
}
```

Comment: Heres your problem: `*(sortedArray++) = *(data++);`

Comment: Here's another one: `swap(&sortedArray[i - 1], &sortedArray[i]);`

Comment: Here's another one: you are not using `std::vector`.

Comment: you are not learning C++, this is C code.

Comment: `I am trying to learn C++ by firstly going through the low level details` While you're doing that, person B *is* learning the higher abstractions, thus producing productive, non-buggy programs.

Comment: What is the issue in *(sortedArray++) = *(data++); ? I am dereferencing source and target array for values, copying the value across, and incrementing pointer. I cannot put parenthesis any other position otherwise it throws error and if I don`t have it then I have same issue.

Comment: @0x499602D2 What is the error there?

Comment: `What is the issue in *(sortedArray++) = *(data++); ` Which side of the `=` gets incremented first?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "Which side of the = gets incremented first?" Why would it matter?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - I guess it doesn't matter in the long run, since the pointer to the allocated memory is now gone anyway.

Comment: @user3722518 - in the code where you called this function, did you attempt to `free` the data allocated by that call to `malloc`?  If you did, what happened?  If you didn't, then that is another issue you need to take heed of, and that is causing memory leaks.

Comment: ...Why didn't you just sort with `data`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`*(sortedArray++) = *(data++);` modifies the pointer so it no longer points to the start of the allocated memory.  So, later on `sortedArray[i]` is whatever happens to be in memory past the array, and accessing it is undefined behavior.

If you must use pointers, a quick fix is to use a temporary one, like:

```
int *sortedArray = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
int* s = sortedArray;
for (int i = 0; i < size;i++){
    *s++ = *data++;
}
```

Another way would be:

```
int *sortedArray = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < size;i++){
    sortedArray[i] = data[i];
}
```

But, the best way would be to use standard containers and algorithms, like `vector` and `sort`.

Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/bbNuVA) of the first fix in action.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, seems quite obvious now ... I plan on looking at the containers shortly, thank you :)

Comment: `error: ‘malloc’ was not declared in this scope`
so just one string should be added `#include <cstdlib>`

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov Ah, in the demo you mean.  It compiles on both ideone and visual studio without it, but I added it anyway to be safest.  I use `malloc` so infrequently I forgot that.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
*(sortedArray++) = *(data++);
```

to

```
sortedArray[i] = data[i];
```

You need to leave intact the pointer to the block of memory you allocated, so you can use it (and free it) later.

Note, there is nothing to be gained by using the `*(x+y)` syntax instead of `x[y]`, they are equivalent but the latter is easier to read.

In C++ you should not use `malloc`. Instead use `new int[size]`.  For `int` there is no difference other than reduced risk of making a typo, however for non-trivial types `malloc` will not construct them correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the advice regarding new [], I will use it from now on.

Answer (score 1):

That is not C++ at all. You can write generic code that takes a `begin` iterator and an `end` iterator in order for it to work with any kind of container that supports such semantic.

```
template<typename IT>
void bubble_sort(IT begin, IT end) {
    while (true) {
        bool swapped = false;
        for (IT i = begin; i != end-1; i = i+1) {
            if (*i > *(i+1)) {
                std::iter_swap(i, i+1);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (swapped == false) return;
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f886ec38f731490f)

Where `std::iter_swap` is like `std::swap` but works on *iterators*. You can see iterators as a pair of pointers to the beginning and (past the) end of a container.

Comment: Can you get even more cryptic, this is not going to help OP.

Comment: It has an error , which can be fixed with a single line.

Comment: @self. That doesn't change the fact that 1) that's not C++; 2) that code should not be perpetuated; 3) he can learn much more from the above code than to an "easy" fix to his.

Comment: OP marked the question with c, c++ and posted some code. Your code is not just diverging from his style, but is completely different, even introducing templates(?) which are completely unnecessary for the problem. You also posted a complete code example which OP can now happily copy/paste. What will he learn from that?

Comment: @self. Marking a question with C **and** C++ makes absolutely no sense at all. We are allowed to just assume he meant C++. It introduces templates because they are a good choice and invites the user to learn about them. If he is just going to copy and paste the code, there's not much I (or you for that matter) that can do for him.

Comment: Sure there is, look at all other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You first pointer `sortedArray` points to some allocated memory.

Then in the first for loop you increment the pointer. not it doesn't point to that memory anymore.

Simply use a temporary pointer for the memory copy.

```
int* t = sortedArray ;
```

And now use `t` in your for loop which copies the data.

Instead of the temporary variable, you can rather count the number of times you called `sortedArray++` in your for loop.

If you take a look: `for (int i = 0; i < size;i++)` you will see that the loop took exactly `size` number of iterations.

Just subtract size from the pointer after the loop and you point back to your allocated memory.

```
sortedArray -= size ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well which doesn`t make use of a auxiliary variable, I didn`t notice this detail.

Comment: Are you actually recommending pointer arithmetics? Is that the kind of the answer the OP (or any new programmer) should learn from? I doubt so.

Comment: @Jefffrey Yes, because he is using pointer arithmetic in his code and that is where the problem was. This was the perfect time to give him some more information on the subject.

Comment: @self. No wonder. Pointer arithmetics often introduce bugs and runtime errors. It is also unreadable and there are way better ways to approach the problem. It is well known in the C++ community that working with pointers is the last thing you want to do. Simple answer is not always the correct one.

Comment: @self. Where have I misinterpreted anything, exactly?

Comment: @Jefffrey Or in other words a logical fallacy.

Comment: @self. You haven't answered my direct question. Is that a logical fallacy?

Comment: @Jefffrey You obviously didn't understand the wikipedia article you have been hastily reading.

Comment: @self. Yes, I've looked on Wikipedia what the straw argument is. I've heard it before on the [Lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) but I don't always remember it's exact meaning, so I've informed myself on it. You are still not answering my question.

Comment: @Jefffrey Yes I choose not to answer pointless and illogical questions.

Comment: @self. Best argument ever. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Jefffrey You even have problems with the basics. That was not an argument but a simple statement.

Comment: @Jefffrey From what I have read there is no mention that pointers are frowned upon, actually I am led to believe they are used in many applications as well as favorite for interviewers to triage with ?

Comment: @user3722518 - It depends on the interview.  If it is for a C++ position, showing off your usage of pointers instead of displaying a working knowledge of the standard library could be a minus, not a plus.